# How to assign webpack loader to exact module name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I created a special loader to import some build-time computed values into my webpack bundle.
I try to assign this loader to match module name `settings`. E.g:

**app.js:**

```js
import settings from 'settings'
console.log(settings.apiUrl)
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```js
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /settings/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: './loaders/settings-loader'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But build fails with message

> ERROR in ./app.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'settings' in '/Users/digger/projects/demo-project'